# Splitting string into two integers

Tags: c, string

I have a string `range` that represents a range, for example:

```
"7-35"
```

I am looking for a simple way to split it into two integers `int begin` and `int end`.
I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472299/split-string-into-tokens-and-save-them-in-an-array) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588975/split-a-string-into-an-integer-array-in-c), but I am actually searching for some kind of a "one line" command if there exist any.
It is actually the opposite of doing:

```
sprintf(range,%d-%d,start,end);
```

Comment: Did you check [sscanf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function?

Comment: Presumably two *positive* integers?

Comment: scanf("%d-%d",&start,&end); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of printing is scanning, and you'd use [`sscanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf):

```
unsigned int start, end;
if(sscanf(range, "%u-%u", &start, &end) == 2)
  printf("start=%u, end=%u\n", start, end);
```

Some notes:

- We use `unsigned int` and `%u` to make the embedded dash non-ambigous
- Always check the return value to make sure the scanning succeeded

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I missed this function. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use sscanf():

```
char *ptr = "7-35";
int i,j;
sscanf(ptr, "%d-%d", &i, &j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
  char sentence []="789-35";

  int start;
  int end;

  sscanf (sentence,"%d %*c %d",&start,&end);
  printf ("start:%d\nend: %d\n",start,end);

return 0;
}
```

I have tested this snippet. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Whats the opposite of printing? Scanning!

Use sscanf

```
sscanf(range,"%d %d", &start, &end);
```